# ClickOnce Updates Not working in Client Machines

Tags: clickonce

I've created a winForms application and I was able to deploy it to a web server. I'm developing on a PC that doesn't belong to the domain that future  users of that app do. The thing is that the machines that installed the app from the web server doesn't perform updates, but my machine(I installed the app to just to try) does all the update work perfectly. Please any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Did you recheck the url for updates?

Comment: Would you please mention what is the Installation URL & the Update Location ?

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to check the installation path and the update path to be sure that it can get new updates.